# jQuery Mobile Enqueue - Loading in WordPress Admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, admin

I've enqueued the scripts properly according to documentation, but jquery mobile still loading in admin.  My code is the following:

```
function mda_script_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_register_script( 'jquerypremobile', get_template_directory_uri() .'/library/js/jquery-pre-mobile.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerypremobile' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquerymobile', 'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1.0' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerymobile' );
        wp_register_script( 'jqueryeffects', get_template_directory_uri() .'/library/js/jquery-effects.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryeffects' );
        wp_register_script( 'nwmatcher', 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/nwapi/nwmatcher/nwmatcher-1.2.5-min.js', false, '1.2.5' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'nwmatcher' );
        wp_register_script( 'superfish', get_template_directory_uri() .'/library/superfish/supersubs.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.4.8' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'superfish' );
        wp_register_script( 'supersubs', get_template_directory_uri() .'/library/superfish/supersubs.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.4.8' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'supersubs' );    
    }
}
add_action('init', 'mda_script_init');
```

Anyone know what's going on? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As it is, this code works for me. Loads in front site, but not in admin...

Comment: i had to install it manually into wp-head and not enqueued as per wordpress best practices to get it not to load in admin. maybe i have some sort of conflict though i shouldn't as i'm using wordpress built-in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
function mda_script_init() {
    wp_register_script( 'jquerypremobile', get_template_directory_uri() .'/library/js/jquery-pre-mobile.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerypremobile' );
    // etc...
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mda_script_init');
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

<sup>*PS: WordPress specific questions are better placed here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/*</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear! I don't ask people to mark my answers as correct, but as you are a new to the Stack community, once a solution is found, you should mark it as such. If you read the entire [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), you'll earn a badge for it and start building your reputation :)